# ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64 build failed

Tags: ios, xcode, duplicates, symbols

I am getting build failed, I tried so many things but I couldn't figure out how to solve it

```
duplicate symbol _GSDK_GTMNSDataZLibExportToSuppressLibToolWarning in:
    /Users/Macpro/Documents/evoteam/ClassifiedTemplate/../Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSData+zlib_external.a(GTMNSData+zlib.o)
    /Users/Macpro/Documents/evoteam/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSData+zlib_external.a(GTMNSData+zlib.o)
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
```

thank you for any help.

Comment: It seems that the file `libGTM_NSData+zlib_external.a` exists in two place?

Comment: I'm also getting same error after updating cocoapods for new Google iOS SDK 2.0.3, Did you find any solution for that ?

` "duplicate symbol _GSDK_GTMNSDataZLibExportToSuppressLibToolWarning in:
   .../Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSData+zlib_external.a(GTMNSData+zlib.o)
    .../Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSData+zlib_external.a(GTMNSData+zlib.o)
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64"

Comment: i still couldn't solve it, it is really frustrating

Answer (score 3):

Add it to your Podfile

```
pod 'Google', '<=1.3.2'
pod 'GoogleUtilities', '<=1.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Google [just fixed](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/193#issuecomment-210232673) the problem: update the pods and everything will be fine.