# duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64 _GSDK_GTMNSDataZLibExportToSuppressLibToolWarning

Tags: ios, sdk, xcode7, linker-errors, google-signin

Getting this error after updating cocoapods for new google ios sdk 2.0.3

```
duplicate symbol _GSDK_GTMNSDataZLibExportToSuppressLibToolWarning in:
../Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSData+zlib_external.a(GTMNSData+zlib.o)
.../Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSData+zlib_external.a(GTMNSData+zlib.o)
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
```

I'm using Xcode Version 7.2.1 (7C1002), My podFile is :

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'
pod 'Google/SignIn'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the discussion and solution mentioned :

https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/193#issuecomment-203736130

Answer (score 0):

may be libGTM_NSData+zlib_external.a file existing more than two times in your project directory, delete duplicate files, it will work.

Comment: Searched in the project, but no duplicate of 'libGTM_NSData+zlib_external.a' found in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64 build failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36216601/ld-1-duplicate-symbol-for-architecture-x86-64-build-failed).

Google [just fixed](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/193#issuecomment-210232673) the problem: update the pods and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution works, but it requires edit actions after each `pod update`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36326278/1219012) is better. Add these strings to the `podfile`:

```
pod 'Google', '<=1.3.2'
pod 'GoogleUtilities', '<=1.1.0'
```